# LINQ2SQL-Update record only if there is an data change

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, orm

I am working on a project which involves fetching sales data from a website and store it in DB. I am using Linq-to-SQL. Is there a way such that the value in database is updated only if there is a change in the new data I fetch?

This is what I tried

```
foreach (var SalesResult in oDailySalesResult)
{
    if (SalesResult.DailySalesResultsID == 0)
    {
       Dc.DailySalesResults.InsertOnSubmit(SalesResult);
       Dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else
    {
       Dc.DailySalesResults.Attach(SalesResult);
       Dc.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, SalesResult);
       Dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

But this just updates the record even though the record has same data that was in the database. Or do you guys have any other solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Attach with one parameter it will assume it is dirty and needs updating. Because : how can it know otherwise?

There are two other forms of attach:

- one takes a bool to indicate clean vs dirty: if you attach it as clean, changes made *after* the attach will be tracked and committed appropriately
- one takes two instances - representing the old values and new values: here again, the differences will be computed and subsequent changes tracked appropriately

Comment: Should i use Refresh too.I tired the second way taking two instance .This updates all the fields even when there is no data change